# Is there any questions on here in relation to only taking "Mr", "Mrs", "Miss" etc at keyboard Input?

Tags: java

This is my code. I only want to accept correct male and female titles. How should I fix this to work because at the moment its not working correctly.

```
boolean valid = false;
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.println("ENTER ACCOUNT DETAILS: ");
do {
    System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
    title = keyboardIn.nextLine();
    if (title.equals("Mr") || title.equals("Mrs") || title.equals("Ms") || title.equals("Miss")) {
        System.out.println("Title set. ");
    }
    name.setTitle(title);
    else {
        System.out.println("Error!, You must enter a correct title. ");
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: "Not working correctly" doesn't really describe the problem.  What does this code actually do?  In what way does it not work as expected?  When you step through in a debugger, where/how does it fail?

Comment: You never seem to set `valid` to `true` .Also, you can't have statements between an `if` block and its corresponding `else` block .

Comment: You must enter a correct title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean valid = false;
Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("ENTER ACCOUNT DETAILS: ");
String title;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
    title = keyboardIn.nextLine();
    if (title.equals("Mr") || title.equals("Mrs") || title.equals("Ms") || title.equals("Miss")) {
        System.out.println("Title set. ");
        name.setTitle(title);
        valid = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error!, You must enter a correct title. ");
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: Thank You. This worked perfectly. I was just not adding the name.setTitle(title);  valid = true; in the if statement. Its working now.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can imagine the reason was that you don't offer any explanation. Answers should be written in such a way that they could also be helpful to others who face similar problems.

Comment: @wvdz thank you, but there are good explanations in comments below the post, so i decided not to copypaste them